# Finding the rank and dimker of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Hi so im working on a question about finding the $rank(A)$ and the $dim(Ker(A))$ of a 7x5 Matrix. Without being given an actual matrix to work from.

I have been told that that the homogeneous equation $A\vec x=\vec0$ has general solution $\vec x=\lambda \vec v$ for some non zero $\vec v$ in $R^{5}$.

So my thinking so far is that I know for an $m*n$ matrix we know that:

$rk(A)+dimker(A)=n$
which must mean that $rk(A)+dimker(A)=5$

but this is where I get stuck and dont know how to proceed.

Any help is greately appreciated.

[image]
.

This is the exact question for the person who asked.

Comment: Now take some examples, like $A=0$, to see what can happen. What you "have been told", is this an assumption? Or do you want to show it? What exactly is the question?

Comment: The $\dim \ker$ is known as the 'nullity'.

Comment: I have added the exact question to my post and "what i have been told" is exactly what I have been told. No assumption. And the exact question is in my first line of text. "finding the $rank(A)$ and the $dim(Ker(A))$ of a 7x5 matrix.

Comment: @TaylorS. The phrase "I have been told" makes it sound as though it was something that was spoken to you in person as opposed to a written part of the question to be answered. For instance, "I have been told" X might mean that when discussing the problem, the class instructor said "you should find that X is true"

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you understand the definition of $\ker(A)$ and the definition of dimension, then you can deduce $\dim \ker A$ from the description of the solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I know that the kernel is the subspace of $R^{5}$ of this matrix consisting of the solutions of the system of linear equations $A\vec x =\vec 0$. And its dimension is called the nullity but im not sure how to utilise this.

Comment: @Taylor You're told that the solution space can be written in the form $S = \{\lambda \vec v: \lambda \in \Bbb R\}$. What is the dimension of this space?

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there any way you could expand on this? I understand that the Kernal is the set of vectors in the domain of the mapping which are mapped to the zero vector. But im not sure how to use this information in the question.

Comment: Is the dimension 1? Im confused on how to figure this out.

Comment: @TaylorS. That's right, the dimension of this space is $1$. In other words the dimension of the *kernel* is $1$

Answer (score 1):

Is $v$ fixed? If yes, then kernel is generated by only this vector, so 1 dimensional. By the formula you wrote, rank is 4.